# Calling the exact method from 2 different NSNotifications concurrently

Tags: ios

In my view controller if I listen for 2 different notifications, but each one calls the exact selector each time, if the selector method is a long running method, will the method get interrupted by the other notification before it's done, or it waits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNotifications` (by default) are delivered on the main `NSOperationQueue`, which is a synchronous queue so only one notification is delivered at a time.  So no, under normal circumstances you won't receive simultaneous notifications, they'll get serialized by the queuing mechanisms.

Note that you can change that by creating your own `NSOperationQueue`, setting the `maxConcurrentOperations` property to a non-one value, and then using `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, it won't interrupt it. I believe that the reason is when your program calls a function the OS allocates a whole new memory bulk for it to execute it under your current executed statements. 
Here's a sample code without using NSNotification

```
dispatch_after(4, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.recieve()
    })
    dispatch_after(5, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.recieve()
    })

func recieve(){
    println("here")
    for index in 1...100000 {
       println(index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried the following code and it confirms my answers.  It does call sequentially

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sel1:) name:@"TEST" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sel1:) name:@"TEST" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TEST" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TEST" object:nil];
}

-(void)sel1:(NSNotification *)noti{

    NSLog(@"Sleeping1");
    sleep(1);
    NSLog(@"wakeing1");


}
```